# How to read a list of gene pairs and write a fasta file for each line

Tags: list, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I'm new to bioinformatics and would really aprecciated some help!

I have a big multi-fasta file (genes.faa), like this:

```
>gene1_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene2_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene3_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene4_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
(...)
```

And a list of gene pairs (gene.pairs.txt), with two genes per line separeted by a tab:

```
gene13_A \t gene33_B
gene2_A \t gene48_B
gene56_A \t gene2_B
```

And I needed a way to read the list of gene pairs and create a fasta file for each line of the list of gene pairs. So, in this case, I would have 3 fasta files (the name of the output fasta files is not important), like this:

fasta1

```
>gene13_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene33_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
```

fasta2

```
>gene2_A 
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene48_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
```

fasta3

```
>gene56_A 
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene2_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
```

I tried to write a script in python but I couldn't find a way to read the list in a loop and write a fasta file for each line.
Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Also, you may want to use [Biopython](https://biopython.org/), specifically [`Bio.SeqIO`](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO). Biopython can be easily installed, for example using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. I have tested on the following files:

Input FASTA file:

```
>gene1_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPA1
>gene2_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPA2
>gene3_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPA3
>gene4_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPA4
```

Gene List file:

```
gene1_A gene3_B
gene2_A gene4_B
```

Code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

my_gene_file   = open('genelist.txt','r')
my_fasta_file  = open('input.fasta','r')

my_list=[]
for line in my_gene_file:
    line = line.strip(' \n')
    gene_id1, gene_id2 = line.split('\t')   
    gene_tuple = (gene_id1, gene_id2)
    my_list.append(gene_tuple)

my_dict={}
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(my_fasta_file, "fasta"):   
    my_dict[seq_record.id] = seq_record.seq

for item in my_list:
    if item[0] in my_dict and item[1] in my_dict:
        output_file_name=(f'{item[0]}_{item[1]}.fasta')
        f = open(output_file_name, "w")
        f.write(f'>{item[0]}\n{my_dict[item[0]]}\n>{item[1]}\n{my_dict[item[1]]}')
```

It outputs files with fasta record ids in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt, sure there are faster better ways to accomplish it, it makes me wonder if there could be a way to skip the creation of the big dictionary : `sequences = { i.id : i for i in SeqIO.parse('big_fasta_2.fa', 'fasta')}`.

I am using the Biopython library to parse the fasta file and to write them https://biopython.org/ ,  https://github.com/biopython/biopython; anyway:

input `'big_fasta_2.fa'` :

```
>gene1_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene2_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene2_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene3_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene4_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAC
>gene13_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAA
>gene33_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAY
>gene48_B
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAW
>gene56_A
MCTGTRNKIIRTCDNCRKRKIKCDRKRPAP
```

input `"gene_pairs_3.txt"`:

```
gene13_A    gene33_B
gene1344_A  gene33_B
gene2_A gene48_B
gene23333_A gene48_B
gene56_A    gene2_B
```

code :

```
from Bio import SeqIO,  __version__

print('Biopython version : ', __version__)


sequences = { i.id : i for i in SeqIO.parse('big_fasta_2.fa', 'fasta')}

print(sequences)


file = open("gene_pairs_3.txt","r")


cnt = 1
for line in file:
    
    
    a, b  =  line.split()
    print('++++++++++++')
    print('pairs N° : ', cnt)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    
    if a in sequences:
        print('ok A')
        print(sequences[a])
        
        if b in sequences:
            print('ok B')
            print(sequences[b])
            
            SeqIO.write([sequences[a],sequences[b]] , 'Fasta'+str(cnt)+'.fa' , 'fasta')
            
            print('\nwritten file : ' ,'Fasta'+str(cnt)+'.fa' )
            
            cnt += 1
        else:
            
            print('No B')
    
    else:
        print('No A')
        continue
    
    print('-----------\n')
```

Have a look at the output files and see if they are what you expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, it does exactly what's expected! As I have a list of 9 000 + pairs of genes, I prefer the other code because it's a bit faster and doesn't print as many things.

Comment: the prints are there just to make it easier to understand how the code works, so that next time you could write your own better https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users